# ExtJS: wrapping pre-existing div into Extjs container

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs

I wonder if there's a method of creating an Extjs container or a panel with the contents taken from a pre-existing element in the page DOM. The page already contains the needed markup in a div, but i'd like to wrap it inside an extjs container and place it into Extjs managed layout.

If you ask why: I'm using ASP.Net MVC templating for creating page markup and would like to keep it this way instead of building the DOM client-side in Javascript or using XTemplates. I'd like to build the html in traditional way and then use client-side Extjs code to set up few containers and layout manager for them.

Comment: We did it this way in our web application before. But as the complexity of UI grew we had to abandon this approach. Having up to 5 grids and a window or two is bearable, but not much more. If your pages are simple, you should be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`contentEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-contentEl) config property. In this config you can specify an existing HTML element, or the id of an existing HTML element to use as the content for component.

HTML inside body:

```
<div id="panelContent">
    Content inside panelContent div
</div>
```

ExtJS panel with div used as its content:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Test Panel',
    width: 200,
    contentEl: 'panelContent',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Fiddle with live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2ji